# How can I sum across rows in data frame and end with a numeric value, even if some values are NA?

Tags: r, sum, na, rowwise

I am attempting to sum the values of columns row-wise, to create a new column with the new values (sum values). Some of the values in the columns are NA, but I'd still like the new column to have a numeric value that represents the other column's values being summed together, row-wise. Does this make sense? I have yet to find any answers and I've tried several codes. I'm a total beginner. Here is what I currently have.

```
minute_totals <- minute_totals %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Days_Minutes_Total = sum(TotalActiveMinutes + SedentaryMinutes + TotalTimeInBed, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  relocate(Days_Minutes_Total, .after = TotalTimeInBed)
```

Now the new dataframe that populates has a column, in the right location, but for every row that was summed with a NA value somewhere, a 0 populates that value box.
I am summing up 3 columns, 2 of which always have numeric values, so at the end, there should always be a numeric value. I also tried:

```
minute_totals <- minute_totals %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Days_Minutes_Total = sum(c_across(TotalActiveMinutes:TotalTimeInBed))) %>% 
  relocate(Days_Minutes_Total, .after = TotalTimeInBed)
```

This populated a sum of NA in my Days_Minutes_Total column, again, even though there were two other columns with numeric values.

I'm not sure how to post the dataframe here, I will try to copy the code to populate that.

```
head(minute_totals)
```

It looks like this:

```
    Id TotalActiveMinu… SedentaryMinutes TotalTimeInBed Days_Minutes_To…
       <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>
1 1503960366              366              728            346             1440
2 1503960366              257              776            407             1440
3 1503960366              222             1218             NA                0
4 1503960366              272              726            442             1440
5 1503960366              267              773            367             1407
6 1503960366              222              539            712             1473
```

Trying to get rid of the 0 and make it 1440, as that is the sum of the first two columns I'm summing up.
Thanks for any pointers and tips, greatly appreciated.

Comment: People will be able to help you better if you provide some sample data. You can add the output of `dput(head(your_data, 20))` to your question.

Comment: Try something like this: `minute_totals %>% mutate(total = rowSums(across(TotalActiveMinutes:TotalTimeInBed), na.rm = TRUE))`.

Comment: Martin, that worked perfectly. Simple, that's all I was trying to do. Thanks. I love using stackOverflow but it's sometimes not the easiest site to wade through...they closed my question saying there are answers already, but all the other answers were for completely different questions, and didn't have exactly what I was trying to do. So I appreciate this simple code. This code is great. It seems so similar to what I tried, just not exact. Strange it didn't work. Is there anything that would make the code I wrote work? Using rowwise, sum, c_across? Just curious.